# Solving T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) - T(n - 3)

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, recurrence

The running time of a some algorithm is given by the recurrence relation

> T(n) = n if n ≤ 3
>
> T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) - T(n-3) otherwise

I know that the order is either n, n<sup>2</sup>, n<sup>n</sup>, or n log n, but I don't know which one. I tried solving this using the substitution method and using the recursion tree method, but couldn't make any progress. Any ideas?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about discrete math, which is more appropriate at math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

This is one where expanding a few terms can help:

- T(1) = 1
- T(2) = 2
- T(3) = 3
- T(4) = T(3) + T(2) - T(1) = 3 + 2 - 1 = 4
- T(5) = T(4) + T(3) - T(2) = 4 + 3 - 2 = 5
- T(6) = T(5) + T(4) - T(3) = 5 + 4 - 3 = 6

The general pattern here seems to be that T(n) = n. We can formalize this with induction:

- T(1) = 1, T(2) = 2, and T(3) = 3 by definition.
- T(n) = T(n - 1) + T(n - 2) - T(n - 3) = n - 1 + n - 2 - n + 3 = 2n + 3 - n - 3 = n

Hope this helps!

Comment: what about if T(n) = T(n-1) + T(n-2) + T(n-3)
also can we use Master Theorem in the case of + T(n-3)

Comment: You can’t use the Master Theorem there because the recurrence doesn’t have the right form. However, you can model that recurrence as a linear homogeneous recurrence relation and solve it using a variety of other techniques. Look up the “annihilator method” for details!